# UIWebView JavaScript Highlight - how to Highlight special characters? (utf8 encoding?)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I was trying to wrap my head around this but I kind of gave up searching. I don't know much about Javascript but I have a .js highlight function for my UIWebView.

My problem is that it does not Highlight text if it includes any special characters like: "',à etc."

I am parsing a NSString onto the .js function which probably is causing the trouble but I can't figure out if I have to parse a utf8 char or if I have to convert the string to utf8 inside my .js.

Here is my .js code

```
function MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element,keyword) {
  if (element) {
    if (element.nodeType == 3) {        // Text node
      while (true) {
        var value = element.nodeValue;  // Search for keyword in text node
        var idx = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword);
        if (idx < 0) break;  // not found, abort
          var span = document.createElement("span");
          var text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx,keyword.length));
          span.appendChild(text);
          span.setAttribute("class","MyAppHighlight");
          span.style.backgroundColor="#C4B695";
          span.style.color="black";
          text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx+keyword.length));
          element.deleteData(idx, value.length - idx);
          var next = element.nextSibling;
          element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, next);
          element.parentNode.insertBefore(text, next);
          element = text;
          span.scrollIntoView();
          MyApp_SearchResultCount++;    // update the counter
        }
      } else if (element.nodeType == 1) { // Element node
          if (element.style.display != "none" && element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'select') {
            for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element.childNodes[i],keyword);
            }
          }
      }
   }
}

// the main entry point to start the search
function MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString(keyword) {
  // MyApp_RemoveAllHighlights();
  MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(document.body, keyword.toLowerCase());
}
```

Please let me know what other information I can provide.

Comment: how can i handle special characters that i parse into my javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case anyone else was wondering about that, the solution was a simple escape character. Thanks everyone.

```
editedSearchString = [editedSearchString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"á" withString:@"\\á"];
```